# Show hidden textbox and label after dropdownlist selectedindex changed

Tags: c#, sharepoint

C# code:

```
    protected void DropDownListDB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownListDB.SelectedValue == "Other")
        {
            LabelIfOtherDb.Visible = true;
            TextBoxIfOtherDb.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

ASP code:

```
                <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="DropDownListDB" runat="server" Height="20px" 
                    Width="158px">
                    <asp:ListItem>- Select -</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Oracle</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MS SQL Server</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MySQL</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MS Access</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have `AutoPostBack="True"` but still it doesn't show my hidden textbox/label.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, your Event is not connected to the event-handler.
Two possibilities: either, define the event-handler in the Markup, like:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="DropDownListDB" runat="server" Height="20px" SelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListDB_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

or in the code-behind

```
DropDownListDB.SelectedIndexChanged += DrowpDownListDB_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

You should put this up in mark-up though.

Comment: Wierd.. I double clicked on my dropdown and then it should automatically create the event handler.. Really wierd hehe, that was the solution ofcourse.. Thank you! Newbie failure ;) hehe

Answer (score 0):

This works have the very same question for a college assignment

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" 
    runat="server" Height="16px" Width="237px" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Comment: Please check out that there is an already existing answer here from a while ago that says pretty much exactly the same thing as you have.